# Convert dict of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a two-level dictionary that looks like this:

```
myDict = {'a':{'2017-01-01':4.1, '2017-01-02':10.8}, 'b':{'2017-01-01':6.2, '2017-01-03':8.5}}
```

I'd want to store this as a dataframe that has the following design:

- Dates for which data exist in one column and not the other column become np.nan in the dataframe - this is nice because I can then use the backfill functions if needed.
- The union of all dates becomes the index and the index is of type pd.DatetimeIndex - this is nice so i can do time operations easily on the dataframe

Dataframe:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,10,np.nan],'b':[6.2,np.nan,8.5]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-04','2017-01-02','2017-01-03']))
mydf.index.name = 'Date'
```

I.e.,

```
mydf
Out[33]: 
               a    b
Date                 
2017-01-04   4.0  6.2
2017-01-02  10.0  NaN
2017-01-03   NaN  8.5
```

The problems I am facing are that of course I don't know in advance which dates comprise the final index (union of all dates), and I also don't know what's the best way to do add data column by column.

The pseudocode I have in mind:

(1) loop across all dates for all keys in level 1 of the dictionary, then take the union of all dates.  This becomes my index.

(2) Then create a new dictionary that only has the original keys and the values in the same order as the index in (1), and np.nan where no values can be found

(3) Use the dictionary in (2) to create the pandas dataframe

However, I see some inefficiencies in this approach in terms of too many loops over the dictionary and copying data more often than potentially required.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trash your pseudocode (sorry!), because pandas got your back with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict, orient='columns')

               a    b
2017-01-01   4.1  6.2
2017-01-02  10.8  NaN
2017-01-03   NaN  8.5
```

The tricky bit is figuring out the right orient to pass... that comes with experience.

Quick note, you may add a `.rename_axis('Date')` call at the end if you want to label the index with the name "Date".

Comment: Note `orient='columns'` is the default, so sometimes you don't even need to guess!

Answer (score 1):

With `pd.Series` (PS: I recommend using `from_dict` provided by cold)

```
pd.Series(myDict).apply(pd.Series).T
Out[615]: 
               a    b
2017-01-01   4.1  6.2
2017-01-02  10.8  NaN
2017-01-03   NaN  8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe from both dict of scalers (players and names) and by unrolling dict of lists (counts, means).

```
pd.DataFrame({'Player':players,'Name':names, **counts, **means})
```